# Send Ansible expect (or shell) module a backspace (to answer a scrpit in term)

Tags: shell, ansible

```
- name : Execute the script and answer to question in term
  expect:
    command: ./"{{ script_name }}"
    responses:
      Question:
        - ''
        - ''
        - ''
        - 'backspace' #?


  become: yes
```

I'd like to use backspace because the script i'm using is answering in advance so that I just have to press enter if i'm ok but for one question i'd like to change the given answer. But so far i didn't find a way to use backspace. Anyone would know ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ASCII control for backspace is `'\b'`. This works with double quotes:

```
- name : Execute the script and answer to question in term
  expect:
  command: "echo Q"
  echo: "yes"
  responses:
   Q: "b\bc"
```

for example returns prints to stdout `1^Hc`, where `^H` is indeed the backspace control.

This may only move the cursor backwards though, not erase the previous character. Just for example, in my bash shell:

```
/bin/bash -c "echo a$'\b'"
```

produces `a` as output, but

```
/bin/bash -c "echo a$'\b'c"
```

produces `c`, since the cursor was moved back, than the `a` was overwritten.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll see if it's working that way in the ansible module, i'm afraid it will only wrotte the letter 'b' as '\' will be interpreted as an escape char ? Tell you more in a few minutes !